# New version of PHPMyAdmin has stopped me being able to edit data

Tags: phpmyadmin

PHPMyAdmin has just been upgraded by my server admin to v4.0.4.2.

Now I am unable to edit rows in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_options` (
  `product_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `option_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`,`option_id`)
)
```

PHPMyAdmin just returns this error message when I browse data in the table:

`This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.`

I don't want a unique column in this table, so how can I edit data?  Is there a setting I can change?

Many thanks

MySQL v5.1.70

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Without unique key, there is no way to differentiate between two same records which can exists. Therefore phpMyAdmin can not safely edit the table - you have no clue which of these would end up edited. Do you really want to have duplicate records in this table?

Comment: well, my table turns out to have only one row, so yes, it could know

Answer (score 15):

All you got to do is add a unique column like one called id with a index = PRIMARY like the pic, or if you have one already that is called id that are numbers just make it PRIMARY

[image]

Comment: @PooyaEstakhri What I did was, first add a column to beginning of table, then choose this settings I called id (but you could already have it chosen) you can call it _id or newId, than if you already have a lot of entries select the A_I box that means Auto Increase so it will number all your passed entries from the first to the last on your actual table giving it a unique number and it will continue numbering all the new entries you enter into the table. that error is because is giving 0 values in all the entries and than is not unique.

Comment: this should be accepted answer instead of that passive aggressive "solution" above

Answer (score 3):

You can just add a field that name is "id", and check A_I option.

Answer (score 1):

Before checking the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option, check that the column is `INT` instead of `VARCHAR`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13866135)

Comment: @ADyson I don't see any links in the answer.

Comment: @Mike Sorry I must have clicked the wrong button in the Review. It's probably worth flagging as being just a comment rather than a full-featured answer though.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which might help someone in future, I had table with id, which was not primary key and not auto increment, i added `temp` column, made it primary and auto increment, then i edited the id column and then i removed the `temp` column, after that i changed `id` to primary and auto increment

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my own case I already had an id column. I dropped the column and recreated it; this time I made it a primary key and ticked A_I (ie Auto-Increment). Everything went fine.

Note: You can only do this if changing your IDs does not affect your work.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you have more than 2 primary keys or you don't have any primary key.