# How can I edit data from a query in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I know this is a very basic question.  I am new to using phpMyAdmin.  I created my database in Access and have now moved it across to phpMyAdmin.  Normally, I would use queries in Access to edit my data.  However, in phpMyAdmin, I cannot edit the data which results from my queries.  There is a message which says "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."  In addition to working out how to edit query results, is there a way of filtering query results, as you can in Access? Also, once the query results were filtered, how can I use a replace function similar to the action which can be performed in Access?

Also, if I wanted to reproduce the forms I was creating on Access, I assume this is not possible through phpMyAdmin.  The webpages are being created in Wordpress.  Is there a plug-in needed to set up something similar to Access forms?

Comment: perhaps missing an index in your table? Or not selecting the index? Show your query.

Comment: So normally you can edit queries in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Queries or results of a query? Yes, you can edit both.

Comment: How? Just by editing the cell contents as you would in Access?

Comment: Yes, in new versions of phpmyadmin that is also possible. Create an index column.
A couple of topics that may help: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227094/new-version-of-phpmyadmin-has-stopped-me-being-able-to-edit-data
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581543/table-with-no-unique-column-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: With reference to the first link, the query is from multiple tables and all the tables already have a primary key (integers, auto-increment)

Comment: without seeing the query and table structure it is difficult to answer

Comment: I added loads of indexes and I was able to do 'filter row', but not edit the query results, but now I can't even do 'filter row' without it throwing up an error message.

Comment: Sorry, cannot be of any help without knowing the structure of your tables, search google for 'phpmyadmin tutorial'

Comment: SELECT LN.LN,WC.WC, WE.Entry, TIN.TWNID, TWN.TWNID,TWN.TWN,WE.MightNeedToChangeTo,WE.FilterX
FROM WE
INNER JOIN WC
ON WE.WCID = WC.WCID
INNER JOIN LN 
ON WE.LNID = LN.LNID
INNER JOIN TIN 
ON WE.TINID = TIN.TINID
INNER JOIN TWN
ON TIN.TWNID = TWN.TWNID
WHERE WE.FilterX IS NOT NULL

Comment: phew... this makes no sense to me and what I would do is rename tables and columns to something meaningfull and study the select and what you want to achieve. Also Explain may help: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Apparently, phpMyAdmin is just alerting us to the fact that there is no way to uniquely identify the rows within this set of results and have found out that we can just add a Unique ID column to this in order to fulfil this need…? 
If this is the solution, to which table do we add this column and from where? 
Is this possible in queries featuring numerous Inner Joins?
Does this need to be done using the CREATE TABLE statement? 
Do we need to add a column for each new query that we run where we wish to edit the results? 
If so, what happens to this once our editing is completed?

Comment: try `select * from WE`, you should be able to edit.. I am not sure if phpmyadmin will allow you to edit data for such a complicated join, you should be able to edit each and every single table there

Comment: here you have some study material for joins: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: It is a normalised relational database, so editing one table at a time will not allow us to edit the data in any meaningful way, as I was able to do in Access.

Comment: The inner joins are correct and the query produces exactly the desired results, but they cannot be edited.

Comment: Try to use different tool if you can, Mysql workbench or Toad comes to my mind